# Can I make apache init run after shared folder is mounted?

Tags: mount, apache2, bootloader, boot-order

Ubuntu 16.04 running on a `vagrant` virtual machine on a Windows 8.1 host.

My `xdebug.ini` file is symlinked to a directory that's shared with the host machine.
(This is so I can create new machines and have `xdebug.ini` set up how I want, and and edits I make to it are always available on the Windows host - I don't have to worry about backing up configurations from the VM)

It seems like the directory is mounted after apache has been started during boot. So I always have to restart apache to load xdebug.

Can I make it so that apache starts *after* the shared directory is mounted? Or automatically restart apache after startup, so I don't have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out an answer. I'm not super familiar with manipulating the linux boot sequence and even though this is a `vagrant` machine, I didn't want to break it.

So I found a `vagrant` solution for my problem.

I just added this bash script, `startup.sh`, to the virtual machine in a directory shared with the host:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

systemctl restart apache2
```

Then I modified my `Vagrantfile` to add the following line:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "startup.sh", run: "always"
```

Or, you could skip the separate bash script and run it `inline` in the `Vagrantfile` as Karl suggested in the comments:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: 'systemctl restart apache2', run: 'always'
```

So, now my VM restarts Apache after boot, and everything works as I wanted it to.

Comment: I was going to make that *exact* recommendation based on reading your question. Good solution! I would have recommended an `inline` script rather than a separate file, since it is a one-liner: `config.vm.provision :shell, inline: 'apache2ctl restart', run: 'always'`

Comment: @KarlWilbur good point about ‘inline’. Thanks!

Comment: Great idea to run it `inline`. To get it to work, I had to add this: `config.vm.provision :shell, inline: 'sudo systemctl restart apache2', run: 'always'`

Comment: @Zeth yes, ‘systemctl’ is the new way to do that in Ubuntu. Updated my answer. I think ‘sudo’ is unnecessary because all the setup is run as root but let me know if I’m mistaken.

Comment: You're right! `sudo` is not necessary (I just tested it). --- In case someone else 'suffers' from the same issue as me, then I got here, when trying to fix this issue for a Vagrant-box. Read more details and solution attempts here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400332/find-reason-for-apache2-service-failed-with-result-exit-code-and-failed-t