# Find reason for "apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'." and "Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server."

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2

I have a VirtualBox setup, with an Ubuntu-machine 20.04 (inside a Vagrant setup), where when I start it up, the apache2-server won't start automatically.

After having started the machine, when I SSH into the machine a write: `sudo service apache2 status`, I see this:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-04-03 21:42:41 CEST; 35s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant apachectl[777]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/host/logs/apache2/sites/' for error>
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant apachectl[777]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/host/logs/apache2/sites/' for error>
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant apachectl[777]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/host/logs/apache2/sites/' for error>
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant apachectl[777]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/host/logs/apache2/sites/' for error>
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant apachectl[777]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant apachectl[759]: Action 'start' failed.
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant apachectl[759]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 03 21:42:41 vagrant systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

It looks like that it cuts off the line, since I would assume it ends with a path, that is chopped off: So that it says (the **bold text** is what I'm missing):

> ... for error log of vhost defined at /et**c/blah/blah/blah**

**Question1:** Where does this status, that is printed with `sudo service apache2 status`, where is that pulled from (so I can see the rest of the line)? **Answer:** It is pulled from: `/var/log/syslog`

**Question2:** Why doesn't my Apache2 want to start when the VM starts?

If I SSH into the machine and write: `sudo service apache2 start` - then it `apache` starts every time. It's just annoying to manually having to do it every time.

---

### Solution attempt 1: Error- and access log

They're both empty, seen like this:

```
$ tail -n 100 /var/log/apache2/error.log /var/log/apache2/access.log

# RESULT:
==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==

==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==
```

---

### Solution attempt 2: Trying to auto-start apache2

I found a solution here: [How to start apache2-server on boot](https://serverfault.com/a/16849), which was this:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults
```

And then run `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up`. But the same error appears.

---

### Solution attempt 3: Play with `/etc/init.d/apache`

I tried playing around with that a bit, starting like this:

```
# Goto dir
cd /etc/init.d/

# See man-pages
man apache2
```

But non of my attempts worked.

---

### Solution attempt 4: Ensure `/host/logs/apache2/sites/` exists

I can see that it exists. Here are the permissions for that folder:

[image: Sites folder]

---

### Solution attempt 5: Check AppArmor

I've never heard of this before. But if I run the command:

```
$ sudo systemctl status apparmor

# Result:
● apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2022-04-01 12:28:20 CEST; 1h 7min ago
```

And if I run the command:

```
$ sudo apparmor_status

# Result: 
apparmor module is loaded.
15 profiles are loaded.
15 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/sbin/haveged
   /usr/sbin/mysqld
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   /{,usr/}sbin/dhclient
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
0 profiles are in complain mode.
2 processes have profiles defined.
2 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/sbin/haveged (533)
   /usr/sbin/mysqld (692)
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

---

### Solution attempt 6: WU-TANG's suggestion from below

It looked like a very probable solution. I did play around with it a lot and sadly didn't get it to work.

This is the output, when I write: `systemctl list-units --type=mount --all`:

```
  UNIT                          LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  -.mount                       loaded active mounted Root Mount
  boot.mount                    loaded active mounted /boot
  dev-hugepages.mount           loaded active mounted Huge Pages File System
  dev-mqueue.mount              loaded active mounted POSIX Message Queue File System
  host.mount                    loaded active mounted /host
  proc-fs-nfsd.mount            loaded active mounted NFSD configuration filesystem
  run-rpc_pipefs.mount          loaded active mounted RPC Pipe File System
  run-user-1000.mount           loaded active mounted /run/user/1000
  sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount loaded active mounted FUSE Control File System
  sys-kernel-config.mount       loaded active mounted Kernel Configuration File System
  sys-kernel-debug.mount        loaded active mounted Kernel Debug File System
  sys-kernel-tracing.mount      loaded active mounted Kernel Trace File System
  var-nfs.mount                 loaded active mounted /var/nfs

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

13 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

And when I write: `sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` I see this:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Documentation=https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried playing around with that `After=...`-line a bunch, where I did a `vagrant halt && vagrant up` afterwards. Regardless of what I do, the problem remains. Here are the different `After=...`-lines I've tried:

```
# Add host.mount
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target host.mount

# Try host.target, since all the other ones are ending with .target
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target host.target

# Try adding the units that had to do with NFS and NFSD
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target host.mount var-nfs.mount proc-fs-nfsd.mount 

# Try adding the units that had to do with NFS and NFSD, but ending with .target
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target host.target var-nfs.target proc-fs-nfsd.target 

# Same thing as the two lines above, but with changed order
After=host.mount var-nfs.mount proc-fs-nfsd.mount network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target 

After=host.target var-nfs.target proc-fs-nfsd.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
```

Still... When starting the VM, the apache-server starts up with the error shown in the beginning of this post.

**Update: Added `vboxadd.service` to the "After=..."-line**:

I also tried the added suggestion by the generous WU-TANG, which made my "After=..."-line look like this:

```
# Attempt1:
After=host.mount vboxadd.service network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

# Attempt2:
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target host.mount vboxadd.service
```

But it still doesn't start `apache`, when I run `vagrant up`.

---

### Quickfix

I found this quickfix-solution, for others facing this issue. It is to add this to the Vagrantfile, just before the last `end`, (so it's inside the `Vagrant.configure( '2' ) do |config|:`-if-statement):

```
# To quick-fix apache not starting, when starting the box
# Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1123052/332403
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: 'sudo systemctl restart apache2', run: 'always'
```

This seems like a "duck-tape"-solution. I was hoping to fix it 'properly', like the direction WU-TANG has been going in.

Comment: The `Cannot access directory '/host/logs/apache2/sites/'` message points to non-existent directories, which would explain the error. Can you confirm if these exist and, if they do, whether AppArmor is enabled 

Comment: Thanks for weighing in @matigo . I've updated my question with answers and details, based on your comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to ensure happen before apache starts.

Mount the custom logs directory/partition **BEFORE** apache starts.

`systemctl list-units --type=mount` hopefully shows you the partition that is not mounting in-time under "DESCRIPTION"... note the **"UNIT"** name in the output.

`systemctl status apache2` provides you the service file location (as you already see). Edit that file, (on the **"Loaded:"** line in the output) and set apache to start after the mounting of that directory.

`sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`
Edit the the **"After="** line to include the noted **"UNIT"** name of the mount partition of the logs... (separated by space, if more than one unit exists there)

You cannot mount a shared drive in virtualbox guests without Guest Additions. Ensure that Guest Additions start running before you start apache. Also on the **"After="** line, append **vboxadd.service**.

save and exit

`journalctl -xe` probably answers your first question.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, @wu-tang . It sounded very plausable, your suggestion here. However, it didn't work. I've added elaborate details to a new *Solution attempt* in the question.

Comment: I would have though host.mount would have been the key... (I still think it may be actually...) I'd be curious to see once it works, if it continues to work without "After=host.mount".... But, in the meantime, you are going to have to provide a lot more detail on that (/host) mount point and its source directory and how that is all configured. I am assuming it is named host for a reason....

Comment: Actually I duplicated the issue, I must have worked on something similar before... it's actually is fairly obvious (if you are familiar with virtualbox i guess) if you look in your logs: /var/log/syslog... and yes you will definitely need to keep my initial answer, as you would never want to start apache without that mount happening first..(host.mount) in your case... see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for yet another suggestion. I tried it and sadly the error persisted :-/ . Thank you so much for your suggestions, WU-TANG !!

Comment: 3 things. 1-Try **vboxadd-service.service**. Shouldn't make a difference because both vboxadd.service and vboxadd-service.service worked to fix the problem for me, but it's worth a shot! 2-It's probably time you show what you have in your /var/log/syslog right before apache tries to start <->fully booted. 3-After your other tests, lets rule out anything else being the problem. Designate all of your apache logs to be in your home drive somewhere and test it. I have the exact results you are getting (word for word), except the above fixes are necessary and work. So you are on the right track.